# Can I use puppet to fully setup a dedicated server with Ubuntu?

Tags: puppet

I see that I can install puppet as an Debian/Ubuntu package to automate deployment.

But can I also bootstrap a full (non-virtual) server including partitioning the hard drives and so on using puppet?

Comment: As toquonce says, typically you use an automated install process and then hand off to puppet after install.

Answer (score 5):

You could partition hard drives using `exec`, but this isn't a good idea, and you would need puppet already installed on the server anyway. Your best bet for automated installing and deployment of bare metal servers would be PXE boot with [Cobbler](http://cobbler.github.com/) and Puppet together.